# Selective display of scalar values in the command window in debug mode

Tags: matlab, debugging

when I run commands in debug mode, it would be useful (in the case of assignment to a 1x1 var) to have the value displayed in the command line by default, as if the statements weren't terminated by semicolon.

Is there a way to automatically display scalar values, without removing the semi-colons by hand?

Comment: You can type their name in the command window

Comment: If you're using the MATLAB IDE, values of variables can be displayed in the Workspace window.  (The top-right window in the default layout I believe.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [marsei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1904719/marsei) proposed, you can use the output of `whos`. But instead of a script, you can write a function and make use of `evalin`, and evaluate this in the `'caller'` workspace, which would be the debugging workspace.

```
function whosscalar()
    vars = evalin('caller', 'whos');
    % filter vars size 1x1 (in case of doubles, 8 bytes)
    vars([vars.bytes] ~= 8 | ~strcmp({vars.class},'double')) = [];
    % sort the scalars by name
    [~, sort_order] = sort(lower({vars.name})); % sort alphabetically 
    vars = vars(sort_order);
    % get values of the variables
    for k = 1:numel(vars)
        vars(k).value = evalin('caller', vars(k).name); 
    end
    % get max length variable name for alignment
    maxlen = max(cellfun( @length, {vars.name}));
    % print the name and value
    for k = 1:numel(vars)
        fprintf('%s\t%s\n', pad(vars(k).name, maxlen), num2str(vars(k).value))
        % instead of num2str and %s you can use %f, %g or some other formatspec. 
    end
end
```

Example:

```
function test()

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = pi;
    d = rand(100);

    fpritnf('a statement\n')

end
```

And in the command window:

```
>> dbstop in test at 8
>> test
8   fpritnf('a statement\n')
K>> whosscalar
a   10
b   20
c   3.1416
K>> dbquit
>>
```

Comment: Nice use of evalin!

Answer (score 1):

The ability to display an entire list of variable values when debugging is not available in MATLAB. To work around this issue, create a file with code similar to the following:

```
myvals = whos;
for n = 1:length(myvals)
    myvals(n).name
    eval(myvals(n).name)
end
```

This script can be called from the `K>>` prompt when debugging MATLAB files to list the values of variables in the base workspace.

An answer from 2010 copied from [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100876-is-there-a-way-to-display-the-values-of-all-variables-in-my-workspace-while-debugging-matlab-code). I still don't know a method for the current 2019b version.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see "it can't be done", I get curious. I think I have found a workaround that is "as simple as it gets" - requiring just a single keystroke.

For this to work you need to define a new function - I chose to call the function `v` for "value" but you can take anything you find easy (source code below). Put this function in your Matlab path, and when you want to do what you're asking for, typing 'v' at the command line will give you just what you need - print the variable name and its value (tested with scalars and strings). For example:

```
>> abc='hello world';
>> v
abc = hello world
>> abc = 123*234;
>> v
abc  =        28782
```

The function could look like this (there are obviously many variations possible...)

```
function v
    % get a trace of all the commands from the command window:
    lc = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
    % the last command is the one-before-last: the last command called this
    % function!
    lastCmd = lc(end-1);

    % split the command at the '=' sign; 
    cmds = split(lastCmd,'=');

    % get the variable name:
    varName = cmds(1);

    % print the result:
    fprintf(1, '%s = ', varName(1));
    % we know the value of the variable in the "caller" space:
    disp(evalin('caller', char(varName(1))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO**

Sorry there is no simple tick box in options which would let you do that automatically. Every workaround will require a bit of effort from you. The most used solutions have been given to you in comments. You could:

- Make use of the [`Workspace Browser`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/workspace.html)
- Simply type the name of the variable in the console
- Select the line you want to run but ommit the `;` from the selection, then press <kbd>F9</kbd>

---

Long answer: **Yes, but you won't like it anyway ...**

If this is really important, there is a way to make the script/function output values in the console when run line by line (or code Section by Section) but it is quite convoluted and require you to code that behavior (it is not an option offered by MATLAB).

For this, when it assign a value, your code needs to know how it has been called. This is done by retrieving the stack trace. The stack trace will list all the functions call tree, so:

- if the current code was called from another function => do not display the output in the console
- if the stack tree is empty, the code has been executed manually => display the output in the console.

This sounds relatively easy, but to implement in all your scripts or functions will be really tedious. Consider the following script: `stackTestScript.m`

```
%% stack test script
a = 3 ;

%%
s = dbstack ;
if isempty(s)
    b = a.^2
else
    b = a.^2 ;
end
```

This script is saved and in the path. If I simply type `stackTestScript` in the console, the script execute, nothing is displayed in the console, but I can see in my [`Workspace Browser`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/workspace.html)(*really a good tool, you should use it*) that I now have a variable `b` having the value `9` => success.

Now if I execute the script section by section, when the second section of code is executed, the console displays:

```
b =
     9
```

This behavior would work exactly the same in a `function`. No difference there.

As you can see, it gives the result you want, but at what cost. You have to repeat every variable assignment twice (one with the `;` and one without) and enclose that in an `if/else` structure with a few lines of code. Huge effort for a single assignment, and you'd have to repeat that for every variable of interest.

Now if you're ready to loose a bit of information, there is a way to make that less tedious. Make a custom function for assignment and do the stack check from within. Consider the following function `dbAssign.m`:

```
function [ value_just_assigned ] = dbAssign( in )
    s = dbstack ;
    if numel(s)<=1
        value_just_assigned = in 
    else
        value_just_assigned = in ;
    end
```

Armed with that, you can now change the initial script `stackTestScript.m` into:

```
%% stack test script
a = 3 ;

%%
b = dbAssign( a.^2 ) ;
```

pfewww, at least now every assignment can fit on one line (although with an unconventional syntax). This works fine when called from another function (no display), but if we run line by line, after execution of the second block we now get in the console:

```
value_just_assigned =
     9
```

You won't be able to know the name of the variable which has been assigned, it will always appear as `value_just_assigned` (or whichever output name you chose to put in `dbAssign.m`). So if you have multiple assignment instructions you will have to keep an eye out for which line you just executed.

There would be a (dirty) way to retrieve the assigned variable name, but only in case it is called by a function, not in the case you want (code executed line by line), so this doesn't help us here.

---

Bottom line, the current tools ([`Workspace Browser`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/workspace.html) yes again) are much more convenient and I wouldn't use any of the code mentionned above in a constant manner (other than for experiment purpose).

There would be some way to push this hack further, but they require to use the `eval` family of functions, which I certainly won't promote here (the code above is already a massive hack, I wouldn't want another (worse) layer on top.)

Comment: thanks for your answers.
"dbAssign" and "whosscalar" are very nice but still ~ manual and don't scale up with the length of the program.. 
My fantasy was of some global setting to use when debugging massive legacy code :)